# Is my TableView in Xamarin.Forms supposed to be gray?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, tableview

**Quick question:** 
Is the TableView in Xamarin.Forms supposed to be all grey like below picture? I was expecting a layout similar to what I'm getting, but with white backgrounds for individual TableSections.

[image: TableView]

Is this because of iOS 14, something I'm doing wrong or maybe the simulator? I'm also experiencing lack of DatePicker and TimePicker support - works on android but not on iPhone simulator, and I was told this issue was the simulator.

I haven't been able to test it on a real device.
I'm posting my code for the Tableview XAML below.

**XAML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    Title="{Binding FullName}"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="ContactBook.ContactsDetailPage">


    <TableView Intent="Form">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection Title="Personal Info">
                <EntryCell Label="First Name" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Keyboard="Text" />
                <EntryCell Label ="Last Name" Text="{Binding LastName}" Keyboard="Text"/>
            </TableSection>

            <TableSection Title="Contact Info">
                <EntryCell Label="Phone" Text="{Binding Phone}" Keyboard="Telephone"/>
                <EntryCell Label="Email" Text="{Binding Email}" Keyboard="Email" />

            </TableSection>

            <TableSection Title="Other">
                <SwitchCell Text="Blocked" On="{Binding IsBlocked}" />
            </TableSection>

            <TableSection>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Button Text="Save" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
                </ViewCell>

            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>

    </TableView>


</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ViewCell` and `StackLayout` to achieve that, becuause xxxCell not contain a `BackgroundColor` pproperty.

For example, code as follows:

```
        <TableSection Title="Contact Info">
            <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="White">
                        <Label Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="Phone" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Entry Text="Binding Phone" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Telephone"/>
                    </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <Label Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="Email" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Entry Text="Binding Email" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Email" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </TableSection>

        <TableSection Title="Other" >
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <Label Margin="15,0,0,0" Text="Blocked" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Switch Margin="280,0,0,0" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </TableSection>

        <TableSection>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
                    <Button Text="Save"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>

        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>

</TableView>
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the solution offered on most forums. I just feel like it defeats the purpose of the TableView however this is properbly the solution om going with, so I'll tag your answer as accepted.

Comment: @MNDevelopments Yes, thanks for marking. Actually it will make other `xxxCell`s will lose their meaning. However, we only can use this as the workaround to achieve our needed effects.

Answer (score 0):

`TableView` has a `BackgroundColor` property that lets you set the background color you want. So if you want it to match the rest of your page, you can do

`<TableView Intent="Form" BackgroundColor="White">`

Comment: Yes, but this changes the entire background color and I still got a formatting that looks off from a standard iOS app. Which has grey background and sections in white.

Comment: Isn't "grey background and sections in white" what your pic already shows? It may help if you mark up the pic which what colors you want to see where.

Comment: No, each section of my view has grey background and when I change the TableView background to white, they get white backgrounds as well. 
I updated the post, and all the black squares indicate where I wanted white background instead of grey. 
Hope it makes sense